# Jest: replace a named import with a value that is different for different tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

Say I have a `some-config-package` dependency that exports a named export called `config`:

some-config-package

```
export const config = {
  featureToggles: {
    someFeatureToggle: false;
  }
};
```

And, say I have a component:

**ComponentAB.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { config } from 'some-config-package';

import A from './A';
import B from './B';

function SomeComponent() => {
  console.log('config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle', config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle);

  return config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle ? <A /> : <B />;
  }
}
```

and I want to test whether the correct content is rendered. In that case, I would like to be able to replace the featureToggle with either `true` or `false`.

So I tried something like this inside the test:

**ComponentAB.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import { config } from 'some-config-package';

import ComponentAB from './ComponentAB.js';

jest.mock("some-config-package");

describe("ComponentAB", () => {
  it.each([
    ['should show A when someFeature is toggled on', true],
    ['should show B when someFeature is toggled off', false]
  ])('%s', (_, someFeatureToggle) => {
    config.featureToggles = {
      someFeatureToggle,
    };

    render(<ComponentAB />);
    
    if (someFeature === true) {
      expect(screenGetByRole('heading'{ name: /Component A/i}).toBeInTheDocument();
    }

    if (someFeature === false) {
      expect(screenGetByRole('heading'{ name: /Component B/i }).toBeInTheDocument();
    }
  }
});
```

Well, that doesn't work. The `console.log` inside `ComponentAB` shows `undefined`, instead of `true`/`false`, and the first test case fails. Second one does not, since `undefined` and `false` are both `falsy`.

So, is what I want possible at all? And if not, how should I go about testing the different scenarios? In my real world case there is more complex logic to test, but this example code is the part I have difficulties with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jest.replaceProperty(object, propertyKey, value)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value).

`ComponentAB.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { config } from './some-config-package';

const A = () => <h1>Component A</h1>;
const B = () => <h1>Component B</h1>;

function SomeComponent() {
    console.log('config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle', config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle);

    return config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle ? <A /> : <B />;
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`some-config-package.js`:

```js
export const config = {
    featureToggles: {
        someFeatureToggle: false,
    },
};
```

`ComponentAB.test.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
import { config } from './some-config-package';
import ComponentAB from './ComponentAB.js';

describe('ComponentAB', () => {
  it.each([
    ['should show A when someFeature is toggled on', true],
    ['should show B when someFeature is toggled off', false],
  ])('%s', (_, someFeatureToggle) => {

    jest.replaceProperty(config.featureToggles, 'someFeatureToggle', someFeatureToggle);

    render(<ComponentAB />);

    if (someFeatureToggle === true) {
      expect(screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /Component A/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
    }

    if (someFeatureToggle === false) {
      expect(screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /Component B/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
    }
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
> jest

  console.log
    config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle true

      at log (stackoverflow/77524390/ComponentAB.js:8:10)

  console.log
    config.featureToggles.someFeatureToggle false

      at log (stackoverflow/77524390/ComponentAB.js:8:10)

 PASS  stackoverflow/77524390/ComponentAB.test.js
  ComponentAB
    ✓ should show A when someFeature is toggled on (44 ms)
    ✓ should show B when someFeature is toggled off (9 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.677 s, estimated 1 s
```